# How to check if a hash key is present in the hash by matching any letter/number for a character {say X}

Tags: perl

I have a hash, say "Identifier" with keys such as FACD,BDCD,DDSE,CDSD. I would like to search if the key "FXXD" is present in the hash "Identifier" by considering X to match any alphanumeric. In this scenario, it should come back with found as "FXXD" matches "FACD" considering X can be anything.

Can hash key search be done by adding a character to match anything?

Any idea would be really helpful?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Hopefully you are NOT using the `X` as a wildcard charter. Reading the comment on @stefan, this is not about 4 letter codes, but actual words. How would you make the difference between searching for "NEXT" should that now return "NEST" too? or looking for "TOXIC" should that return "TOPIC"? ... Please consider 'non-word' character for wild-cards. A commonly used character is `?`. Regular Expressions have their built-in and are shown below in the `grep` commands. @Shawn is giving a very good solution, where he first substitutes the `X` for `[[:alnum]]` which matches alph-numericals.

Answer (score 5):

To select keys that satisfy a pattern

```
my @spec_keys = grep { /F..D/ } keys %identifier;
```

where the `F..D` pattern can be anywhere in the key. If it should match the key without any leading or trailing characters then anchor it, `/^F..D$/`.

Answer (score 5):

First, turn the X's in your string into a regular expression character class that matches a single alphanumeric character, and then the good old `grep`/`keys`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;

my $test = { FACD => 1, BDCD => 1, DDSE => 1, CDSD => 1, QFADD => 1 };

sub matches {
  my ($hash, $key) = @_;

  # X matches all alphanumeric characters
  $key =~ s/X/[[:alnum:]]/g;
  my $pat = qr/^$key$/;
  return grep { m/$pat/ } keys %$hash;
}

for (qw/FXXD FXDD BXXX/) {
  say $_, (matches($test, $_) ? " matches!" : " doesn't match!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No you can't. A single hash is the wrong approach for this kind of search.

If your keys are fixed sized, e.g. 4 characters long as per your example, you could use multiple hashes. Here is a sketch of the algorithm:

```perl
my %first = (
   A => { AAAA => 1, ... all keys starting with A... },
   ...
);
my %second = {
   A => { AAAA => 1, ... all keys having A as 2nd character... },
   ...
);
my %third  = ...
my %fourth = ...

# match first (F) and last (D) character in key
my $matches_first = $first{F};
my $matches_last  = $fourth{D};
my @matches =
    grep { exists $matches_fourth->{$_} }
    keys %{ $matches_first };
```

In a real program you would generate the contents of `%first` etc from the list of keys and calculate the match code from the search pattern.

```perl
foreach my $c ('A'..'Z') {
    $first{$c}  = {};
    $second{$c} = {};
    $third{$c}  = {};
    $fourth{$c} = {}; 
}
foreach my $key (keys %identifier) {
    my($c1, $c2, $c3, $c4) = split(//, $key);
    $first{$c1}->{$key}++;
    $second{$c2}->{$key}++;
    $third{$c3}->{$key}++;
    $fourth($c4}->{$key}++;
}
```

**EDIT 2:** Depending on the amount of your data it might also be possible to use a simple search function, e.g. for your example

```perl
my @matches = grep { /^F..D$/ } keys %identifier;
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, Stefan! Actually, the keys are not of fixed length. Very dynamic. Examples:my keys could be MATERIAL1, SOFTWAREV1P2, HARDWAREV5P2.  I could search to see MATXXXALX, SXFXWAREVXPX, XARDWAREX5X2 exist in the hash (the character "X" is the keypoint).

Comment: Then the 2nd solution is better unless you have a lot of keys to search through. The 1st solution can be adapted for keys of any (well reasonable) length keys, but I would then add another hash `( 1 => ... keys of length 1.., 2 => ... )` to quickly access those keys with the correct length

Answer (score 1):

If you're not too concerned with performance, you could use [Tie::Hash::Regex](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::Regex).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Tie::Hash::Regex;

my %hash : Regex;

%hash = (
  FACD => 1,
  BDCD => 1,
  DDSE => 1,
  CDSD => 1,
);

if (exists $hash{'F\w\wD'}) {
  say 'Found key matching FXXD';
} else {
  say 'No key matching FXXD';
}
```

[Full disclosure - I wrote this module as a stupid demonstration of tying. I don't really recommend that you use it in production.]